# Django deletes previous entry when submiting new one

Tags: python, django

Title is pretty self-explanatory the thing is when I try to submit a new entry django deletes the previous one. I think that the problem is in the delete function because when I disable it I can sumbit as many entries as I want. Here are my files:

**Form.py**

```
class FinancesForm(forms.Form):
description = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
value = forms.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Finances(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
value = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, null = True)
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def finances(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FinancesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newEntry = Finances()
            newEntry.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            newEntry.value = form.cleaned_data['value']
            if Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('value')).values()[0] == None:
               newEntry.total = newEntry.value;
            else:
                newEntry.total = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('value')).values()[0] + newEntry.value
            newEntry.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('finances'))

    form = Finances()
    entries = Finances.objects.all()
    total = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('value')).values()[0]

    return render(request, 'coop/finances.html', {'entries': entries, 'form':form, 'total': total})

@login_required
def fdelete(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise HTTP404

    entryId = request.POST.get('entry', None)
    entToDel = get_object_or_404(Finances, pk = entryId)
    entToDel.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('finances'))
```

**Finances.html**

```
<tbody>
      {% if entries %}
      {% for entry in entries %}
      {% if forloop.last %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ entry.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
        {% if entry.value >= 0 %}
        <td class="positive">{{ entry.value }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td class="negative">{{ entry.value}}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{entry.total}}</td>
        <td>
          <form action="{% url "fdelete" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="entry" value="{{ entry.pk }}"/>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Eliminar"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% else %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ entry.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
        {% if entry.value >= 0 %}
        <td class="positive">{{ entry.value }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td class="negative">{{ entry.value}}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{entry.total}}</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <form class="input-group" action="{% url "finances" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Concepte" name="description"/></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Quantitat    €" name="value" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"/></td>
        </form>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tbody>
```

Thanks for yout time

Comment: Could you also provide urls connected with those views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed your first form

```
    <td>
      <form action="{% url "fdelete" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="entry" value="{{ entry.pk }}"/>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Eliminar"/>
    </td>
```

Add closing `</form>` tag